# Buddypress - when user activates account,user role changes to default

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Iam working with buddypress,
I have a two user roles,
1-student 
2-faculty
and i have set default user role as subscriber.
when user registers and activates account by clicking on link sent through mail.User role changes to default(subscriber).

Any idea what is the issue? Below is the code assigning role to user on sign up.

```
add_action('bp_core_signup_user', 'ad_user_signup_usermeta', 10, 5);
function ad_user_signup_usermeta($user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta) {

        if(isset($_POST['signup_membership']) && !empty($_POST['signup_membership']))
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'membership', $_POST['signup_membership']);

        $userdata = array();
        $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
        if(!empty($_POST['signup_usertype'])) {
            if($_POST['signup_usertype'] == 'student') {
            $userdata['role'] = 'student';  
            }
            if($_POST['signup_usertype'] == 'instructor') {
            $userdata['role'] = 'instructor';   
            }   
        }

        if ($userdata['role']){
            wp_update_user($userdata);
        }

}
```

Comment: Maybe 'instructor' and 'student' should begin with an uppercase letter?

Comment: But i have this roles predefined same how it is shown in above code.Only during activating account,user role changes to default user role.

Answer (score 2):

Upon activation, BuddyPress (at least version 2.0.2) updates the user's role to the default role.

https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.0.2/bp-members/bp-members-functions.php#L1560

You can comment out that line, or write some code to work around it. I'm using "WP Roles At Registration" and ran across the same problem. I ended up adding a filter on `bp_core_signup_user` to save the original role but you'll want to add something like this to your ad_user_signup_usermeta:

```
update_user_meta($user_id, 'temp_role', $role_name)
```

then reset it back in a filter for `bp_core_activated_user`

```
public function after_bp_activated_user($user_id, $key, $user) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $role = get_user_meta($user_id, 'temp_role');
    if ($role) {
        $user->set_role($role[0]);
    }
}
add_filter('bp_core_activated_user', array($this, 'after_bp_activated_user'), 30, 3);
```

Comment: Hi Ryduh, I am using the same plugin "WP Roles At Registration" and have the same problem you have, since i am fairly new at this could you please explain your solution a bit more, not getting it completely. Thank you very much, i have been wrecking my brain on that one :)

Comment: @Nec BP triggers the `bp_core_activated_user` hook after the user has been activated. This code listens for that trigger, and then takes the user id that BP sends as an argument, loads up that user from the database, and then adds the temp_role role to that user